# Ionic not working in emulator but working browser

Tags: ionic4

My ionic angular application is working in Browser but when I build and run in android emulator it's not working. There is nor CORS issues.

Comment: What command are your running? What does your console say is the error when you run a build command?

Comment: @haron68 There are no errors. I'm using the ionic capacitor command to build android app after that I open the android project from android studio and build apk or testing in the emulator.

Comment: Have you looked into whether your app is not running in android because the android emulator doesn't configure localhost like iOS or browser does at IP 127.0.0.1 but rather at IP 10.0.0.2